# Feel like something

Tags: american-english

**1.** Does the structure 'feel like doing sth' stand for a polite way of 'want' in AmE or it's British?
For instance do you Americans possibly say:

> - I felt like swimming.

---

**2.** Do these sentences mean the same:

> - What would you like to drink?
> - What do you feel like drinking?

OR

> - Would you like some tea?
> - Do you feel like some tea?

I guess they should be the same and normal in AmE polite language. I was wondering if I thought properly.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom "feel like something/doing something" is used in an informal way both in American and British English. When you have a wish, desire or inclination for something, you can use it in a normal way.  It's nothing to do with politeness or impolitenesss.  Besides, its use in the form of a question is seldom. The usual and polite way for offers and invitations is using "would" such as "Would you like a coffee?" or "What would you like to drink?" or "Would you have dinner with me tomorrow?".

I don't mean that you can not say "Do you feel like some coffee?" There is nothing wrong with it grammatically. What I mean is that we use this idiom in an ordinary way.  It's just like when you ask somebody "Are you in the mood for dancing?"
It's a normal way of speaking.

Answer (score 0):

They do, indeed, mean the same thing, and can be used interchangeably. I don't actually think there's much difference in terms of formality or politeness.